Interpretación de Java Mission Control
Tengo un microservicio en Java 8 y SpringBoot el cual estoy monitoreando el uso de la memoria por medio de parámetros en la JVM y CPU, esto para simular un ambiente de contenedores (no tengo acceso a él), al realizar una grabación con JMV no me queda claro cual es la memoria utilizada para el tiempo de la petición.
Sin embargo en una sección del reporte Memory Allocated for TLABs es muy grande la diferencia, cuándo limitó la memoria el valor es de 756.21Mb, sino se limita se reduce a 79.68Mb.
¿Este valor es el de la memoria?

El valor que ves en "Memory Allocated for TLABs" solo te muestra la memoria que los hilos están usando para pequeñas asignaciones, pero no te da una imagen completa del uso total de memoria.
La diferencia que notas al limitar la memoria significa que la JVM está cambiando cómo maneja la asignación de memoria cuando tiene menos espacio disponible.
Si quieres saber cuánta memoria está usando tu microservicio en total durante una petición, deberías mirar las secciones de "Heap Usage" y el comportamiento del Garbage Collector en el reporte de Java Mission Control. Eso te dará un panorama más claro del uso real de memoria.
